# Canvas PutImageData color loss with no/low alpha

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

There's a 3x3 image. The CanvasPixelArray is:

```
[12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255,12,24,48,255]
```

I change the alpha of all pixels to 0 and back by:

```
bobs = this.gfx.getImageData(0,0,3,3).data
for (a=3;a<bobs.data.length;a+=4)
bobs.data[a] = 0
this.gfx.putImageData(bobs,0,0)
bobs = this.gfx.getImageData(0,0,3,3).data
for (a=3;a<bobs.data.length;a+=4)
bobs.data[a] = 255
this.gfx.putImageData(bobs,0,0)
```

All pixels became black. The browser changed the colors to black to save memory. Is there a way to prevent this or should I save a duplicate?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the context? Where do you need to use this? It might be cool to have a concrete example to play with at http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason for this is that Canvas uses premultiplied alpha, meaning all rgb values are multiplied by the alpha value for those pixels.  It's done to speed up alpha blending with backgrounds, etc.

There's a section on premultiplied alpha in this article: [wikipedia:Alpha_compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

You'll probably have to either, as you say keep a copy of the unmodified values, or perhaps store an alpha value for the image and set the globalAlpha property before drawing the image.
(When I say image, you can equally create a 3x3 canvas, store the pixels there and use drawImage() to draw it to the main canvas).

Comment: So is this a browser bug, or does the HTML5 canvas spec allow for color loss due to premultiplied alpha handling?

Comment: Never mind, it's allowed by the spec, http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html: "Due to the lossy nature of converting to and from premultiplied alpha color values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData() might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values."