# Image alpha on default Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, alpha

I'm trying to duotone an image and plaster it onto a canvas.

Works in desktop browsers:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- Internet Explorer

Fails in mobile browsers:

- Android

[Workable demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJPS4/), this example works in Chrome but fails in Android's default browser.

> [image]

The code is:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: gray;
    }
</style>

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="64" height="64"></canvas>

<script>
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'image.png';

    image.onload = function () { //once the image finishes loading
        var context = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
        var pixels = imageData.data;
        var numPixels = pixels.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { //for every pixel in the image
            var index = i * 4;
            var average = (pixels[index] + pixels[index + 1] + pixels[index + 2]) / 3;

            pixels[index] = average + 255; //red is increased
            pixels[index + 1] = average; //green
            pixels[index + 2] = average; //blue
            //pixels[index + 3] = pixels[index + 3]; //no changes to alpha
        }

        context.clearRect(0, 0, 64, 64); //clear the image
        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); //places the modified image instead
    }
</script>
```

The summary is:

- set the background color to gray so alpha can be observed easier
- create a canvas 64 by 64
- load a image of a smiley face on a transparent background
- draw the image onto the canvas
- get the image's data
- for every pixel, make the red stronger
- replace the altered image on the canvas

The smiley face looks like this (block-quoted so you can tell it's transparent):

> [image]

However, in comparison with the chrome and android browser,

> [image]

The background of the android drawing is reddish while the chrome drawing is completely transparent.

So...

- What happened here?
- How can I change the code so that the android drawing matches with the chrome drawing?

**Note**: I already tried `if (pixels[index + 3] == 0) continue;`, and I'm aware of this, but it won't work for images with varying opacity.

Comment: Have you saved your png in the 24- format?

Comment: @romaneso No, it's a 32-bit RGBA. I don't even think 24-bit RGBA is even possible, considering RGBA [requires 32 bits](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/PixelSamples32bppRGBA.png).

Comment: Oh, thats correct. Try it as a gif maybe

Comment: @romaneso Seems to have the same result
 with a PNG. The background on chrome is completely transparent while the background on my android device is tinted red.

Comment: i get Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. when im testing your code. Have you been checking for errors contributing to this color-difference?

Comment: @Thouartamazing You have to download the image and place it in your testing area (because cross domain rules apply). As for checking errors, I console.log'd the alphas and they were zero in places that should be zero, which should result in a transparent image, but as seen, does not.

Comment: I did download your image, and i didnt change your code at all.  I just had to rename your image to image.png.  Google chrome has... technical difficulties sometimes. it worked in firefox

Comment: @Thouartamazing It also has to be running on a webserver, making a `.html` file and running it straight with chrome will not work. It also should be on a webserver so you can test it with an android device.

Comment: ah. try .drawImage() and see the result.  It yealded quite a few answers when i had similar problems.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: @Thouartamazing Sorry I don't understand, I am using `.drawImage()` in the above code. I first draw the image onto the canvas, then I'm changing the image by making red stronger.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the way the android browser handles the lossy nature check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497925/how-can-i-stop-the-alpha-premultiplication-with-canvas-imagedata/23501676#23501676) for a better explanation of what I mean.

Comment: @Loktar Doesn't this only change the colors? In [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883220/canvas-putimagedata-color-loss-with-no-low-alpha), it seems only the colors changes, while the alpha works. In this case, I'm not touching the alpha, will this still mess up the alpha?

Comment: @DaveChen I'm not 100% its really the only thing I can think of though that *could* cause an issue like that besides an outright browser bug :?

Comment: @DaveChen I couldn't recreate this, but a suggestion: limit the red to 255 :  pixels[index] = 255; or  pixels[index] = Math.min(255, average + 255);

Comment: @yoah It has the same effect even if I set a value directly, `pixels[index] = 120`. Are you saying that when you visit the fiddle on your android, that it is not surrounded by a tinted red background?

Comment: @DaveChen yes, with fiddle on nexus 1 usinh old Android browser, or on a few new devices with Chrome, I do not get get the tinted background

Comment: Have you tried gif, but use a background color (most go for pink) then if pink set alpha to 0 this way your forcing it to be set to transparent in the canvas

Comment: Maybe can be related with this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17565 ?

Comment: @MartinBarker I have tried something similar, `if (pixels[index + 3] == 0) continue;` and it works, but as stated in the question above, I need varying opacity.

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani Looks like exactly what I'm going through. In my experience however, those support forums never actually have any solutions. (Opened in 2011 in this case, and still nothing) I'll probably star it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have a [`result`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/3UrG3/).

First of all look at your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { //for every pixel in the image
     var index = i * 4;
```

`index` will be more than 3 times bigger than `numPixels`. And will get `undefined` values. And average will be `NaN`. But, then I fixed this - result was the same.

So I tried to use `fillStyle` and `fillRect` for every pixel. All becomes fine. My [`code`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/3UrG3/):

```
function putImageData(ctx, imageData, dx, dy, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyWidth, dirtyHeight) {
    var data = imageData.data;
    var height = imageData.height;
    var width = imageData.width;

    dirtyX = dirtyX || 0;
    dirtyY = dirtyY || 0;
    dirtyWidth = dirtyWidth !== undefined ? dirtyWidth : width;
    dirtyHeight = dirtyHeight !== undefined ? dirtyHeight : height;

    var limitBottom = dirtyY + dirtyHeight;
    var limitRight = dirtyX + dirtyWidth;

    for (var y = dirtyY; y < limitBottom; y++) {
        for (var x = dirtyX; x < limitRight; x++) {
            var pos = y * width + x;
            //adding red increased here
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + data[pos * 4 + 0] + 255 + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 1] + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 2] + ',' + (data[pos * 4 + 3] / 255) + ')';
            ctx.fillRect(x + dx, y + dy, 1, 1);
        }
    }
};

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

image.onload = function () {
    var context = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d"),
        imageData;

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);

    putImageData(context, imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I accepted + bounty because it's essentially not a problem with the code, but a problem with the JavaScript implementation Android browsers use. By utilizing fillRect, it's a much slower, but at least an effective way to apply the same effects onto the image.